# Using RESTful services with JAX-RS/CXF in Tomcat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, cxf, jax-rs

I'm interested in using Apache's JAX-RS implementation (CXF) in a Tomcat environment. The [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html) is pretty clear and straight forward about developing a RESTful service with JAX-RS/CXF. However, I'm not sure how to develop a JAX-RS service within the context of a Tomcat environment.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial on developing JAX-RS/CXF services for Tomcat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly a tutorial, but there is nothing special in developing JAX-RS in Tomcat (after all it is based on the servlet specification, which tomcat supports):

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html

(in particular under the heading Configuring JAX-RS services in container without Spring)

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial how to developing a resful services with jax-rs/cxf in tomcat:
http://javajeedevelopment.blogspot.fr/2014/07/restful-services-using-apache-cxf.html